# Control Pc program via SMS

Tags: sms, controls

Is there a way to control a PC program via SMS?For example i would like to send something like "open google" and have firefox open google.

I heard a GSM modem is needed.is that right?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a GSM modem to send or receive small numbers of SMSs.  For large numbers of SMSes, there are commercial services where you pay them and send and receive files of SMSes over an internet connection, and they take care of the sending over the GSM network.

If you are talking about sending an SMS to a modem on an unknown computer, and gaining control of it, then you're in the realms of illegal activity.

But if you control the remote PC, then yes, it's possible.  One obvious way, would be to have a modem with activated SIM attached to the remote PC; install an application written by you that would monitor the modem and read incoming SMSes, and carry out tasks according to the contents of the SMSes.

Bear in mind that that normal use of a modem would be to make an IP connection over a data network like GPRS, UMTS or LTE, and download data from the internet.  SMS could be useful if you can't make a data connection, e.g. if there is only a basic GSM network available, or if your SIM doesn't have a data tarif.